# Как создать ProgressBar в фрагменте?

Tags: android

```
В моем приложении одна активность и ряд фрагментов. Во втором фрагменте мне нужно создать ProgressBar (файлы подгружаюся через сеть - использую AsyncTask, поэтому в onPreExecute мне нужно инициализировать мой ProgressBar).
Проблема в следующем:
AsyncTask мне нужно запускать только из метода onCreate(), так как если запустить рабочий поток из onCreateView() при обратной навигации опять вылазит индикатор загрузки (срабатывает onCreateView() со всеми вытекающими последствиями...).
Но я не понимаю как в onPreExecute можно добавить проинициализированный progressBar  к контейнеру или макету, если он еще не готов (ведь метод onCreateView() срабатывает после onPreExecute)?

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        //some code...
         new FetchItemsTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.fragment_id);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        setupAdapter();
        return view;
    }

 public class FetchItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,TeamStanding> {
private ProgressBar progressBar;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            progressBar = new ProgressBar(getActivity());
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setMax(mNumberOfTeams);
//???????????????????????????????????????????????
        }
//some code...
}
```

Comment: сделайте проверку в onCreateView if (savedInstanceState == null) { new FetchItemsTask().execute(); } тогда будет срабатывать только при первом запуске

Comment: Ваше приложение переворачивается? Если да, то AsyncTask не вариант. Правильней, запускать сервис в нем новый поток и потом передавать инфу в Активити. А еще лучше сохранять в базу и загружать оттуда. Прогресс бар, круглый (бесконечный) прятать при завершении загрузке и все.

Comment: да, переворачивается. Сейчас поиграюсь с этим. Спасибо.

Comment: При перевороте активити создается заново и все его View, фрагменты и т.д. И ваша, AsyncTask'a запустится снова. Сервисы не зависят от жизненного цикла Активити. Почитайте эту тему, про нее 100500 статей.

Comment: Говоря о сервисах Вы подразумеваете ExecuterService и использование интерфейса Future<V>?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=en - на Английском  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html?hl=ru - на Русском

Comment: Спасибо за инфу!  Похоже, придется все перестраивать...

Comment: Лучше так, чем потом мучатся. На эту тему есть куча видео, на youtube разные каналы связанные с Андроид разработкой, посмотрите.